# Change default settings/extensions for new profiles

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Is there a way predefine settings, install extensions, etc, so when a new profile is created or browser launched with `--user-data-dir` argument pointed to an empty folder, it would already have these settings changed, extensions installed, etc?

Comment: Yes; It requires you to install the Administrative Templates and configure the group policies.

Comment: Is this the group policies you are referring to? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhdNi.png I don't see how settings, for instance, for devtools window can be changed from there... Also, what about ms edge?

Comment: To manage MS Edge you would have to install its Administrative Template.